# SXA Search box Suggestion Error

Tags: sxa

SXA Search box Suggestion component, returns error in specific cases if the returned results contain chars like "." or "\" for example.

Any one faced this issue before?
[image]

[image]

Comment: This actually looks like a bug. I will try to confirm this and register as an issue in our backlog. I'll keep you updated.

Comment: Thanks Dawid, Please let me know if there is a temp fix for this error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to use suggestions please remember that you need to have:

- at least Sitecore 9.0
- Solr

Before first usage you need to:

1. In the `solrconfig.xml` for your index, you need to add suggest searchComponent and component need to be called **sxaSuggester**.
2. Create /suggest requestHandler in the same file
3. Build the suggester http://localhost:8983/solr/sitecore_sxa_master_index/suggest?suggest.build=true. This will also tell you if your component is working fine.
4. And you can query for some suggestions: http://localhost:8983/solr/sitecore_sxa_master_index/suggest?suggest.q=test

Keep in mind that what you will see depends on Solr configuration. There are thousands of possible suggestion configurations on Solr!

Regarding your issue: I can confirm that it was a bug and will be fixed in SXA 1.7.1. The problem was in this line:

[image]

As a quick workaround while waiting for SXA 1.7.1 you can replace this line with: `text = data.html.replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/ig, "")`.